# Can I install Xcode 4 from the App Store on multiple Macs?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Now that Xcode is part of the App Store (I'm not a paid developer yet) I have to pay $5 for it, which is fine. However, I am wondering if I have to pay $5 for every one of my Macs? Or what if I blow my current Mac and do a reinstall, do I have to pay for Xcode again?

Comment: You can have up to 5 installs on different computers at the same time of any application on the Mac App Store.  That's because you can only link 5 computers to your account at one time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6283/can-i-install-apps-bought-on-appstore-on-multiple-computers) will answer your question! :)

Answer from link:

> Yes. Just run the App Store app on the second Mac and go to the Purchases tab. You'll see a list of the apps you've already purchased, with an Install button next to each one - click the button to install on the second Mac.

Answer (score 2):

The Mac App store allows you to redownload previously purchased apps. So you would just have to link your Apple account to the new machine and then you should be able to download it on that machine with no additional charge.

Answer (score 1):

According to the terms and conditions:
http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/us/terms.html#APPS

"MAC APP STORE PRODUCT USAGE RULES

Except as otherwise set forth herein,

(i) You may download and use an application from the Mac App Store (“Mac App Store Product”) for personal, non-commercial use on any Apple-branded products running Mac OS X (“Mac Computer”) that you own or control. "

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed, my other apps are available for download from my other computers. So my guess is that it will be the same for Xcode 4!

I will confirm once I try it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install the same app on another Mac; I just did it. And if you've already downloaded the Install Xcode.app, you can copy that already downloaded file into the applications of the other computer and the Mac App Store will see it is already installed.

Warning: Do not remove the Install Xcode.app or the store will no longer think you have it installed, even though it is.