# Is it possible to install Xcode 4.3.2 on multiple macs from a single download?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, installation

I recently updated xcode to 4.3.2 on my macbook via the app store. Because of the really poor internet connection here, it took me over 12 hours to do this, and now I have to replicate this on other development machines.

Is there some way to move the completed installation to the other systems? Perhaps a temporary installer exists somewhere on the system that I can archive for future use?

It's worth noting that this question:

[Can I install Xcode 4 from the App Store on multiple Macs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356736/can-i-install-xcode-4-from-the-app-store-on-multiple-macs)

does not speak to my issue because 4.3.2 does not include the "install xcode.app" file.

Or am I doomed to have to redownload from the mac app store on each machine? :-(

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to just copy XCode.app (inside /Applications) from one Mac to another?.. App Store should be "only" able to download a single bundle.. (like previously, "Install XCode.app"). I would be interested in the result of this procedure. (i just don't have more macs to try)

Comment: I didn't consider this....I just thought it must have downloaded a temporary installer and deleted it afterwards. I was hoping to get some insight on this from the SO community.....

Comment: If i understand the App Store mechanism corect it works as following: Authorize Download > Download package (ipa-like) > Extract package content ("Payload" directory) to /Applications / Register Metadata (.plist). I believe the App Store is not capable of performing any form of intelligent installation - this is why we had/have "Mac OS X Lion Installation.app", "Install XCode.app", new "XCode.app". The new XCode.app also asks to install a Mobile Device Support Framework itself and wants to delete any /Developer install. This obviously can't be done by Mac App Store

Comment: I hesistated for the following reasons:

* I don't know how it will handle frameworks and so forth
* I don't know whether i got a "custom download" based on my currently installed version of scode
* I don't know if it downloaded an "install xcode" app and deleted it afterwards
* the download size was about 1.9 gigs but xcode.app is over 3 gigs! I wondered if xcode.app was indeed the file that was downloaded, or was it just updated by another (now deleted) .app file?

In any case you've given me the confidence to try copypasting the xcode.app. I'll get back to you on that.

Comment: The same as the lion install, if you run it, it deletes the original. Download it, copy the xcode install elsewhere, install it. You can use the xcode installer on whatever machine you have as long as it meets the minimum requirements. I have

Comment: It's just that beginning with XCode 4.3 there is no more "installer" app, just XCode.app itself.

Comment: according to fs_usage tool, the App Store's storeagent downloads a .pkg, then uses PraveFrameworks/PackageKit.framework to extract its content and registers the download to some .plists. nothing more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For members of the developer program, Xcode can also be [downloaded from Apple's site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action), without the App Store.  I know you don't want to do another download.  I'm just mentioning this because the download you get from there is just a disk image with Xcode.app in it.  To install, you just drag that Xcode.app to wherever you like, just like any ordinary Mac app.

That strongly suggests to me that you can just copy the Xcode.app that you got from the Mac App Store, too. That said, it may also try to download additional things. For example, doc sets and the Command Line Tools component.

Comment: I am going to try to just drag xcode.app across as you and martin suggested, and if it works I will come back and accept this answer since martin put his as a comment. I dont know how to credit him (if this works that is)

Also, that DMG is exactly what i need if the drag-and-drop method fails, so I guess I will accept this answer immediately!!!!

Comment: This is the correct answer. The Xcode.app can be copied to any other mac and executed there. I think this is actually a step forward by apple, amazing portability. Kudos to them.

Answer (score 0):

As @KenThomases mentioned, Xcode can be downloaded outside the App Store. This is the recommended approach if you want to deploy it on multiple Macs without the hassle of Apple IDs.

Plus, there's an app for this now: [xcode-installer gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/xcode-installer)